# Record square video - Flutter

Tags: flutter, video, camera, video-capture

I have this scenario:

i have an app that records video and this video must be square, for this reason in build method I setup camera preview in this way:

```
var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

      return Container(
          width:  size,
          height: size,
          child: ClipRect(
            child: OverflowBox(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                child: Container(
                  width:  size / _controller.value.previewSize.width,
                  height:
                  size / _controller.value.previewSize.height,
                  child: CameraPreview(this._controller), // this is my CameraPreview
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

In this way video is square but only in visualization, when I export it it is rectangular.

There is a way to set the aspect ratio of the camera in order to have a square video output?